# Abline for gls won't plot

Tags: r

I am attempting to plot the model below with a regression line, and I can generate a plot but none of the abline commands I have tried (also below) seem to work. R will appear to be happy and not output any error messages with the first abline command I try, but no line will appear on the plot. I've tried adding the abline function into the plot code itself too but this hasn't worked either. Any help would be appreciated.

```
model2<-gls(transformedlongevity~transformedproportion, data=independencedata, 
            correlation=corPagel(1,trimtree))
summary(model2)
plot(model2, xlab= "Transformed Value of Proportion of Life Spent Under Parental Care (Years)", 
     ylab="Transformed Value of Maximum Life Span (Years)", 
     main= "Time Spent Under Parental Care Relative 
     to Longevity of Passerine Species")


abline(gls(transformedproportion~transformedlongevity, independencedata), untf=T)
abline(a=0, b=coef(model2)) 
abline(coef(model2))
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dput(independencedata)` after editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please include the package used in your post. So if your `gls` comes from `nlme` then the plot you are seeing is for residuals, not predicted values. Using an example set from nlme:

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- gls(follicles ~ Time, Ovary,
            correlation = corAR1(form = ~ 1 | Mare))
plot(fm1)
```

[image]

So a fitted line doesn't make sense here. You most likely want to do:

```
plot(Ovary$Time,Ovary$follicles)
abline(fm1,col="blue")
```